# how can a word add in keep its documents under custody?

Tags: ms-word, vsto, ms-office

I am developing a Word add in that is intended to create randomizable test bank documents. I would like the add in to prevent user entry outside content fields where there will be texts of questions and choices. I tried protection applied outside the content controls, but that requires the add in to frequently unprotect and reprotect the documents with the risk of any intervening error leaving the document unprotected.

If anyone can suggest an alternative method, I will appreciate it.

Hurol Aslan

Comment: How are your test documents used? Asking, because if I wanted to create "fake" test documents, an Add-In does not sound like the most obvious choice.

Comment: My add-in will enable the user to create question groups as rich text content controls. Each group control is created with a table that will contain a question field (also a rich text content control) with its own table for multiple choices, each choice being another rich text content control. A question can also contain plain text content controls for the user to insert randomizable numerical values and randomly selected list entries. An add-in sounded like a better choice than a document project, because it enables the users to create multiple test banks and share them with each other.

Comment: Oh I see, I had completely misunderstood your goal - your add-in creates tests, like school exams, correct? Then you are right, an add-in is a perfectly valid approach.

Answer (score 0):

After trying the protect/unprotected approach, I found that it does not let me nest a locked content control (for providing code-defined content) within a content control open to editing. However, I can set LockContents properties of nested content controls independently. That is the approach I will go with.